can useBlocker be used on the very first page?
I have a form on the very first page of a SPA, which uses react router v6, that should block the back navigation, on specific cases. to simplify this, we can say it must always block the back navigation, when on the first rendered page.
unfortunately, useBlocker does not block it: all the following navigations will block the back navigation, is useBlocker is called correctly, but not on the very first one.
To try this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-58ojzsnc?file=README.md
Is this expected? How could I workaround this?

Do you happen to have better exact reproduction steps? When I open your sandbox I'm already only on the initial page and there is no history to issue a back navigation action to. That said, in modern/current UI/UX design it has become quite anti-pattern to block navigation actions, forwards or backwards. The recommendation these days is to simply listen for the events to happen and silently persist or cleanup data/resources and let the user do what they are indicating they wish to do, e.g. they want to navigate, so just let them.

You can replicate it by opening the running example: https://github58ojzsnc-mpcv--3000--c8c182a3.local-corp.webcontainer.io/

When I try that I get a "Could not find project" error page.

you can open the original link and use the "open preview in new tab" button. with that temporary link you can fiddle around, visit a page beforehand and then navigate it to check if the navigation block works. or you can navigate it straightforwardly: the back will show the blank tab

plus: UI/UX could vary a lot, depending on the context. in this specific case the SPA is "simulating" an app, and the blocking would help the user to not navigate back from an important form with unsaved data. that's expected even from classic applications like text editors etc.

"that's expected even from classic applications like text editors etc" - No, that's exactly the problem current UI/UX avoids. Blocking navigation is now considered to be a poor user experience. If there is unsaved data the recommendation is to save/persist it for the user so when they navigate back on the page the app can "re-hydrate" the "unsaved data" back into the UI for the user... or throw it away if it doesn't really matter.

that's a good discussion point for ux.stackexchange.com but it goes beyond the technical issue I'm presenting.Back to the technical issue: is there a way to accomplish this?


we can say it must always block the back navigation, when on the first
rendered page.
unfortunately, useBlocker does not block it: all the following
navigations will block the back navigation, is useBlocker is called
correctly, but not on the very first one.
Is this expected?

I believe this is the designed/expected behavior. The useBlocker function description is (emphasis is mine):
useBlocker

Allow the application to block navigations within the SPA and present
the user a confirmation dialog to confirm the navigation. Mostly used
to avoid using half-filled form data. This does not handle
hard-reloads or cross-origin navigations.

Meaning if the user does a hard page reload or navigates to/from another domain/origin that the navigation action will not be blocked.

How could I workaround this?

You could implement your own beforeunload* event handler that would handle the page reload and page unloading because the user left your domain cases.
Example:
const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

// Cache the current input value in a React ref
const valueRef = React.useRef(value);
React.useEffect(() => {
  valueRef.current = value;
}, [value]);

// Instantiate "beforeunload" event listener + callback
React.useEffect(() => {
  const handleBeforeUnload = (event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
    // Only if page data is dirty prevent the unload event and check with user
    if (valueRef.current) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = ''; // **
      return '';              // **
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
  };
}, []);

*Note: Review the complete beforeunload event docs for full details and caveats.
**Note: You can return a string message here and some browsers might "honor" it and display it instead of a now-standardized message. For example Chrome just displays "Changes you made may not be saved." in a confirmation dialog regardless what you return/specify.
